# How come changing the bool into any datatype, code still works perfect?

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

When given a number `n`, the program examines `n`'s digits one at a time, storing each into the `digit` variable and then using it as an index into `digit_seen`.

If `digit_seen[ digit ]` is false, then digit has not been seen before, so the program sets `digit_seen[ digit ]` to true and keeps on going. As explained in *C programming - Modern approach by K.N. King*:

Note well!

Changing the bool data type to any data type (char, int, float) still gives the correct results. How is it not a case???

```
/*
** Checks number for repeated digits
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int digit;  
    bool digit_seen[ 10 ] = { false };
    long n;

    printf( "Enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%ld", &n );

    while( n > 0 ){
        digit = n % 10;
        if( digit_seen[ digit ] )
            break;
        digit_seen[ digit ] = true;
        n /= 10;
    }

    if( n > 0 )
        printf( "Repeated digit\n" );
    else
        printf( "No repeated digit\n" );

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check `<stdbool.h>` library you will find:

```
#define false 0
#define true  1
```

Any primitive type is capable of holding these two values.

Comment: "Any" sounds like a challenge for how to create a "type" that does not work (very easy in c++) but with c it may come down to compiler nuances with things where sizeof would be 0.

Comment: @Abel, yes, but that's not really functional though, these will fit in anything down to one bit. Still it deserves a clarification, I don't want people fighting over this :)

Comment: @anastaciu it might not be functional but it still works perfect. One thing for sure is that it's hard to debug such a mistake because the complier even won't warn.The question is that does it have any side effects???

Comment: @Aaronnevalinz I was talking about the zero size created types, this does not apply to your question, it's perfectly valid to use primitive types as boolean, the conditions in C are if it's 0 is false if it's any other value it's true, it's common to use int return type functions as condition, the classic example is `if(strcmp(...))`, the side effect is readability of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In C, conditions (in while/for loops, if, etc ...) just test if an expression evaluates to something not equal to 0.

So:

```
if (a)
```

Is the same thing as:

```
if (a != 0)
```

Booleans in C are just defined as a type that can take one of two values, true (1) and false (0).

Operators `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `&&`, `||` and `!` are all operators that result with 1 or 0.